# Inconsistent image move behavior in quilljs with react

Tags: image, google-chrome, reactjs, typescript, quill

i have encountered an issue, when making a text editor with support of image based tags. There is a need to move those tags around freely in the text, which is being made impractical by this issue.

Basically when I start dragging an image, and then drop it on desired location, one of two results can happen: A) it works as intended and B) the image is dropped to the end/beginning of the sentence. You can see the behaviour in attached gif. [Resulting behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMF6i.gif)

I'm using react and typescript combination for creating the page with quill being inserted in a component.

```js
// TextEditor/index.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import * as Quill from 'quill';

import { TextEditorState, TextEditorProps } from '../@types';
import { generateDelta } from '../@utils/generateDelta';

const formats = [
  'image'
];

class TextEditor extends React.Component<TextEditorProps, TextEditorState> {
  constructor(props: TextEditorProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Editor: undefined
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const self = this;
    this.setState({Editor: new Quill('#editor-container', {formats: formats, debug: 'warn'})});
    
  }

  changeText(text: string) {
    if(typeof(this.state.Editor) !== 'undefined') {
      this.state.Editor.setContents(generateDelta(text), 'api');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="editor-container"></div>
    );
  }
}

export default TextEditor;
```

And the usage of this component in another component is just

```js
// editor.tsx
import TextEditor from '../QuillEditor/TextEditor';

...

onUpdate(text: string) {
  this.refs.targetEditor.changeText(text);
}

...
render() {
  return (
    ...
    <TextEditor
      ref={'targetEditor'}
    />
    ...
  )
}
```

I have tried to change the text editor to just contentEditable div and that worked flawlessly, so it shouldn't be because of some css glitch.

Has anyone some idea of what could be causing this?

**EDIT Feb 6**:
I have found out, that this issue is manifesting only in Chrome, as IE and MS Edge did not encountered this issue. I have tried to switch off all extensions, yet the issue is still there. Private mode also didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

After few days of research I have figured out what is causing the issue.

The combination of Quill and React won't work, because of the way React 'steals' input events, while creating the shadow DOM. Basically, because it tries to process my input in contenteditable div created by Quill, it causes some actions to not fire, resulting in the weird behaviour. And because Quill tries to do it by itself, outside of React DOM.

This I have proved in my simple testing project, where adding a simple input tag anywhere on the page broke down the Quill editor.

Possible solution would be to use react-quill or some other component container, however I haven't managed to make it successfully work, or write some yourself, which would incorporate Quill to React in its DOM compatible way.